# Updating my custom module to Drupal 7

Tags: hooks

I have updated a module from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7, but the following code doesn't work anymore. I have updated the .info file, but the module still doesn't work.

```
function header_image_block($op='list',$delta=0,$edit=array()) {
   if ($op=='list') {
     $blocks[0] = array(
       'info' => t('Header image'),
     );
     return $blocks;
   }

   elseif ($op == 'view') {
     $block = array(
       'subject' => 'Header Images',
       'content' => changeHeader(),
     );
     return $block;
   }
}

function changeHeader() {
  $output = '';
  $output = '<img src = "' . base_path() . 'sites/all/themes/optimiza/images/imge-header.png" border = "0" />';
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1))) {
    $nid = arg(1);
    $node = node_load($nid);
    $path = $node->field_head_img[0]['filepath'];
    if ($path != '') {
      $output = '<img src = "' . base_path() . $path . '" border = "0" />';
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7, instead of `hook_block()` there are more hooks:

- [hook_block_info()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7)
- [hook_block_configure()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7)
- [hook_block_save()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_save/7)
- [hook_block_view()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7)

In short, you need to split the Drupal 6 code for `hook_block()` between those hooks.

As side notes:

- Every function implemented from a module should be prefixed by the module short name
- To load the node, you should use the following code.

  ```
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    // The page is a node page.
  }
  ```
- To access the content of a field, you should use the following code.

  ```
  $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_head_img');
  $path = $items[0]['filepath'];
  ```
- To output an image, you should use [theme('image')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7), or [theme('image_style')](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7). As you are outputting a field, you should use [field_view_field()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_field/7), as in the following code.

  ```
  $output = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_head_img');
  ```